# Yahoo Answers API + php Scraper

Tags: php, yahoo-api, scraper

I have found a [php script](http://hungrycoder.xenexbd.com/scripts/php-scripts-2/searching-and-retrieving-yahoo-answers-in-php.html) that would in theorie match my needs, however I cant get it to work and I was wondering if maybe the script is outdated or if I am doing something wrong.

The script looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Yahoo Answer
 * @author The HungryCoder
 * @link http://hungrycoder.xenexbd.com/?p=953
 * @version 1.0
 * @license GPL, This class does not come with any expressed or implied warranties! Use at your own risks!  
 */

class yahooAnswer{
    var $appID;
    var $searchQuestionURL = 'http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?';
    var $getQuestionURL = 'http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/getQuestion?';

    private $numResults = 10;
    private $numStart = 0;

    function  __construct($appid) {

        $this->appID=$appid;
    }

    function set_numResults($num_results){
        $this->numResults = $num_results;
    }

    /**
     * Search for questions for the given keywords. Returned results can be associative array or XML
     * @param <string> $kewyord
     * @return <string> Returns the results set either in XML format or associative array. 
     */

    function search_questions($params){
        if(!is_array($params)){
            throw new Exception('The parameters must be an array!');
        }
        $defaults = array(
            'search_in'     =>  '',
            'category_name' =>  '',
            'date_range'    =>  '', //7, 7-30, 30-60, 60-90, more90
            'sort'          =>  'relevance', //relevance, date_desc, date_asc
            'type'          =>  'all',
            'output'        =>  'php',
            'results'       =>  $this->numResults,
            'start'         =>  $this->numStart,
            'region'        =>  'us',
            'appid'         =>  $this->appID,
        );
        $params = array_merge($defaults,$params);

        if(!$params['appid']){
            throw new Exception('APP ID is empty!', 404);
        }
        if(!$params['query']) {
            throw new Exception('Query is not set!', '404');
        }

        $req_params = $this->array2query_string($params);

        $url = $this->searchQuestionURL.$req_params;
        $results = $this->make_call($url);
        if($params['output']=='php'){
            $results = unserialize($results);
            return $results['Questions'];
        }
        return $results;

    }


    /**
     * Get all answers of a given question ID
     * @param <array> $params keys are: question_id, output, appid
     * @return <string> Returns all answers in expected format. default format is php array
     */

    function get_question($params){

         if(!is_array($params)){
            throw new Exception('The parameter must be an array!');
        }
        $defaults = array(
            'question_id'   =>  '',
            'output'        =>  'php',
            'appid'         =>  $this->appID,
        );
        $params = array_merge($defaults,$params);



        if(!$params['appid']){
            throw new Exception('APP ID is empty!', 404);
        }
        if(!$params['question_id']) {
            throw new Exception('Question ID is not set!', '404');
        }


        $req_params = $this->array2query_string($params);


        $url = $this->getQuestionURL.$req_params;
        $results = $this->make_call($url);
        if($params['output']=='php'){
            $results = unserialize($results);
            return $results['Questions'][0];
        }
        return $results;
    }


    protected function make_call($url){
        if(function_exists('curl_init')){
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $result;
        } else if(function_exists('file_get_contents')) {
            return file_get_contents($url);
        } else {
            throw new Exception('No method available to contact remote server! We must need cURL or file_get_contents()!', '500');
        }
    }

    protected  function array2query_string($array){
        if(!is_array($array)) throw new Exception('Parameter must be an array', '500');
        $params ='';
        foreach($array as $key=>$val){
            $params .= "$key=$val&";
        }
        return $params;
    }
}

$appid = 'MYAPPID';
$params = array(
    'query'     =>      'test',   //enter your keyword here. this will be searched on yahoo answer
    'results'   =>       2,         //number of questions it should return
    'type'      =>      'resolved',  //only resolved questiosn will be returned. other values can be all, open, undecided
    'output'    =>      'php',      //result will be PHP array. Other values can be xml, json, rss
);

$question_id  = 'test'; //without this i get an error "Question ID is not set!"

$yn = new yahooAnswer($appid);
//search questions
try{
    $questions = $yn->search_questions($params);
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    //now get the answers for the question_id;
    try{
        $answers = $yn->get_question(array('question_id'=>$question_id));
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($answers);
        echo '<pre>';
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo($e->getMessage());
    }

}

?>
```

But instead of a valid output I just get this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 
    [type] => 
    [Subject] => 
    [Content] => 
    [Date] => 
    [Timestamp] => 
    [Link] => http://answers.yahoo.com/question/?qid=
    [Category] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [content] => 
        )

    [UserId] => 
    [UserNick] => 
    [UserPhotoURL] => 
    [NumAnswers] => 
    [NumComments] => 
    [ChosenAnswer] => 
    [ChosenAnswererId] => 
    [ChosenAnswererNick] => 
    [ChosenAnswerTimestamp] => 
    [ChosenAnswerAwardTimestamp] => 
)
```

I have tried it with other keywords, but the result is always the same.

This part `$question_id  = 'test';` is not included in the official script, but without it I keep getting `Question ID is not set!`.

I also tried to change it, add it at another place in the script etc. Everything I could think of, but the result was always that array with no information besides the `[Link]`

Since I got almost zero php experience at all, I am not even where start looking for an error :/ Would be glad if some1 could point me in the right direction!

Regards!

p.s. of course "MYAPPID" is changed to my real yahoo app id.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this example work, change this line:

`$answers = $yn->get_question(array('question_id'=>$question_id));`

to:

`$answers = $yn->get_question(array('question_id'=>$question['id']));`

That change pulls the actual question ID out of the response from `search_questions()`, and uses it in the call to `get_question()`.